# Angular 14 default value for mat-select doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14, mat-select

In this code if I click on edit button the selection menu appears with default value of column.field as set in [formControlName] with name *Material Name*.The code was working properly in angular 13 but after migrating to angular 14, by clicking on edit button the selection doesn't show its default value.
Is there any idea that what's wrong with it?

html:

```
 <div [formGroup]="basketFormGroup" class=" custom-table-style" style="width: 100%;">

              <table *ngIf="formArray1" formArrayName="formArray" mat-table [dataSource]="basketLayerData">

                <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [matColumnDef]="column.field">

                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header-color">
                    <div [style]="column.styles">{{column.header}}</div>

                  </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row, let formIndex=index" [formGroupName]="formIndex">
                    <div fxHide.gt-xs>{{ column.header }} :</div>
                    <div class="cell-div" [style]="column.styles">
                      <!-- *ngIf="(editFlag && column.header == 'Code') || (editFlag && column.header == 'Description') " -->
                      <mat-form-field *ngIf="column.header != 'Material Name' " appearance="outline">
                        <input type="number" style="color: #1a3d78; font-weight: normal; width: 98%;" matInput
                          [formControlName]="column.field">

                      </mat-form-field>

                      <mat-form-field *ngIf="column.header == 'Material Name'" appearance="outline">
                        <input *ngIf="!editFlag" type="text" style="color: #1a3d78; font-weight: normal; width: 98%;" matInput
                          [formControlName]="column.field">
                          <mat-select *ngIf="editFlag" [formControlName]="column.field">
                            <!-- <mat-label>{{}}</mat-label> -->
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let ScrapMaterial of basketInfoService.allScrapMaterials let i=index" [value]="ScrapMaterial.materialName"
                                         (click)="onSelect(formIndex,ScrapMaterial.idMaterial)">
                              {{ScrapMaterial.materialName}}
                            </mat-option>
                          </mat-select>
                      </mat-form-field>

                                       </div>

                  </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns;sticky: true"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index;" (click)="onBasketInfoTableClicked(i)"
                  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': selectedIndex == i ? 'yellow' : 'white' }" class="main-heat-row">
                </tr>

              </table>

            </div>
```

ts:

```
  formStartup(datasource: any[]) {
    let formArrayControl = <UntypedFormArray>this.basketFormGroup.get("formArray");
    formArrayControl.controls.length = 0;
    let i = 0;

    this.basketLayerData.forEach(element => {
      // console.log("aa", element.basketMaterialInfoId);

      formArrayControl.push(this.fb.group({
        materialName: [element.material.materialName, Validators.required],
        materialWeight: [element.materialWeight, Validators.required],
        materialId: [element.materialId, Validators.required],
        basketMaterialInfoId: [element.basketMaterialInfoId],
        idBasketInfo: [element.idBasketInfo]
      }))
      i += 1;
    });

    this.formSubscription = this.basketFormGroup.get('formArray').valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
    })


    if (!this.editFlag) {
      formArrayControl.disable();
      // this.disabledForm = true;
    }

  }

  onEditClicked() {
    if (!this.editFlag) {
      this.editFlag = true;
      this.basketInfoService.editFlag.next(true);

      let formArrayControl = <UntypedFormArray>this.basketFormGroup.get("formArray");
      formArrayControl.enable();
      // clearInterval(this.elecProfService.getElecProfile);
    }

    else
      console.log("edit is already enabled!")
  }

  onSelect( formIndex: number, idMaterial: number) {
    let row = this.formArray1.controls[formIndex];
    row.get('materialId').setValue(idMaterial);

  }
```

I used [(value)] for mat-select but still nothing shows.

Comment: Did you update Angular Material? Maybe using [value]?

Comment: Angular Material version is 14.2.0. @René. what's your idea then?

Comment: Did you change versions in your `package.json`? Have you tried removing node_modules and reinstalling again, maybe using `npm ci`?

Comment: I just updated Angular version from 13 to 14. Reinstalling with` npm ci` doesn't work. still value is not set in mat-select when edit button is clicked :( @René

Comment: No, the Angular Material version

Comment: I finally used ngDefaultControl in mat-select and also compareFn to solve this problem :) hope it helps other that might have faced similar problem.